# Explain this "cross-multiplication"

Tags: linear-algebra

I am working out a text book problem, in one of the steps the author takes two linear equations with 3 variables each...

$$
l(2)+m(3)+n(1)=0\tag{1}
$$

$$
l(1)+m(2)+n(-1)=0\tag{2}
$$

...and arrives at 3 fractions equal to each other.

$$
\frac{l}{3(-1)-(1)(2)}=\frac{m}{(1)(1)-2(-1)}=\frac{n}{(2)(2)-(3)(1)}\tag{3}
$$

He claims to be using "the rule of cross-multiplication" but this is one variation of the rule I am not aware of or have forgotten.

Please explain how it works.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm looking at this as finding a vector, $\langle l,m,n \rangle$ orthogonal to both the vectors $\langle 2,3,1 \rangle$ and $\langle 1, 2, -1\rangle$.  The denominators in your equation (3) are the components of the cross product $\langle 2,3,1 \rangle \times \langle 1, 2, -1 \rangle$.  And we need $l$, $m$, $n$ to be proportional to these components.

Comment: So the author meant "cross product" and not "cross-multiplication"? You are right about the vector math! This is from a text by Arshad Qureshi well-known in India.

Comment: Of course I can't say for sure what the author meant, but this seems like a possibility.